# Calling a function within a function inside an object literal

Tags: javascript

So I'm doing a tutorial on one of the videos I found online. In that tutorial, he used **IIFE** to create mvc model rather than **object literals**.

I decided to recreate the project using **object literals**

This is the problem that I am having right now and I'm not sure what the problem is. I suspect it has something to do with **scoping problem**.

This is the code for the controller and at the end I initiate the init().

```
var model ={ //Code }
var view = {//Code}

var controller = {
    dom: view.getDom(),
    setEventHandler: function(){
       document.addEventListener("keypress", function(ev){
          if(ev.keyCode === 13){
             this.addItem();
          }
      });
    },

    addItem: function(){
      this.updateMethod();
      // Code
    },
    init: function(){
       this.setupEventHandler();
    },
    updateMethod: function(){
       // Some code
    }


{

controller.init();
```

Now when I press the enter key to invoke the event, i get an error from the console. It states:

"Uncaught TypeError: this.addItem is not a function at HTMLDocument.[anonymous]"

**Question:**
Why is it not recognizing the addItem()?

The same error message occurs within addItem() when I try to invoke this.updateMethod() too.

One way I found to have this.addItem() to get invoked in the event listener is by using **() =>** rather than using a regular anonymous function declaration.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", (ev) => {
   if(ev.keyCode === 13){
      this.addItem();
   {
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, the value of `this` is determined by how function is called. In your example, `this` refers to element on which event is bound.

There are few of ways,

1. Using [**`Function#bind`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
2. Using [**`Arrow Function`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
3. Keeping `this` in variable

> Using `Function#bind`

```
var model = {};
var view = {};
var controller = {
  dom: view.getDom(),
  setEventHandler: function() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(ev) {
      if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
        this.addItem();
      }
    }.bind(this));
  },
  addItem: function() {
    this.updateMethod();
    // Code
  },
  init: function() {
    this.setupEventHandler();
  },
  updateMethod: function() {
    // Some code
  }
};
controller.init();
```

> Using Arrow Function:

```
var model = {};
var view = {};
var controller = {
  dom: view.getDom(),
  setEventHandler: function() {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", (ev) => {
      if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
        this.addItem();
      }
    });
  },
  addItem: function() {
    this.updateMethod();
    // Code
  },
  init: function() {
    this.setupEventHandler();
  },
  updateMethod: function() {
    // Some code
  }
};
controller.init();
```

> Using variable holding `this` context

```
var model = {};
var view = {};
var controller = {
  dom: view.getDom(),
  setEventHandler: function() {
    var _this = this;
    document.addEventListener("keypress", function(ev) {
      if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
        _this.addItem();
      }
    });
  },
  addItem: function() {
    this.updateMethod();
    // Code
  },
  init: function() {
    this.setupEventHandler();
  },
  updateMethod: function() {
    // Some code
  }
};
controller.init();
```

Comment: There are more ways: refering to `controller` instead of `this`; using arrow functions.

Comment: @NaïmFavier - I was editing that Sir :) Thanks...

Comment: This is really  just a duplicate of one of the top 3 most linked questions in javascript tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @charlietfl - Yeah! You are right...

Comment: Felix's answer is even more detailed also. That's why he created it as a canonical answer

Answer (score 0):

> *Question: Why is it not recognizing the addItem()?*
>
> ...
>
> *One way I found to have this.addItem() to get invoked in the event listener is by using () => rather than using a regular anonymous function declaration.*

Because with traditional function syntax, the value of `this` is bound by the caller, so it becomes the bound element. Whereas an arrow function does not bind its own `this` value, it will use the `this` from the `setEventHandler` method, which will be a reference to `controller`.

Be aware that `init` calls `setupEventHandler` but it should be `setEventHandler`.